# Results is not defined- NODE js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ejs

como andan? es la primera vez que escribo aca y estoy buscando un poco de ayuda!  estoy programando un proyecto que involucra bases de datos y resulta que quiero hacer una lista con todos los usuarios registrados con un forEach pero no me deja agregarlo y me lanza este error: results is not defined. Use Nodejs, EJS, MySQL. Dejo las capturas, desde ya muchas gracias!!!!

JavaScript:

```js
    app.get('/turnos', (req, res) => {
        conexion.query("SELECT * FROM turnos WHERE DNI= ?", [DNI], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(results)
                res.render('turnos.ejs', { results: results });
            }
        })
    })
```

html:

```html
<tbody>
    <% results.forEach((dni)=> { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= dni.fecha %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= dni.hora %>
            </td>
    
            <td>
                <a href="/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-outline-info"><i class='bx bxs-edit'></i></a>
                <a href="/delete/<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class='bx bxs-trash-alt'></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <%= }); %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hola, ahi lo edite, por favor confirmar si se ve bien!gracias!!

Comment: Aplicaste `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`?

Comment: si, aplique app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Comment: me indica que el error esta en la linea que contiene <% results.forEach((dni)=> { %>, alguien sabe que otro elemento puedo utilizar para cambiar el forEarch?